# How can get instance of class knowing its (string)name in runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, silverlight-4.0, user-controls

everyone. I operate with WP7.
I have a `ListBox`.

Items in that `ListBox` must look very different. Each element is special.

What I did. I've created a simple **dataTemplate** for `ListBoxItem`. There is only **ContentPresenter** and nothing more.

And **Content** property **ContentPresenter** of is binding to **DataContext.Content**

Also I've created several userConrols that represent a special content for each element.

```
specialObject one = new specialObject();
one.textString = "one"; //data of object
oneButtonPanel b1 = new oneButtonPanel(); //look of object

specialObject two = new specialObject();
two.textString = "two"; //data of object
two_butonsPanel b2 = new two_butonsPanel(); //look of object

one.Content = b1; //set up Content property
b1.DataContext = one;
two.Content = b2;
b2.DataContext = two; //set up Content property        

ObservableCollection<specialObject> colItems = new ObservableCollection<specialObject>() { one, two };
myListBox.ItemsSource = colItems;
```

And everything works fine. But I don't know which `UserControl` I have to create actually.

```
two_butons b2 = new two_butons(); // Any other class can be here. I know only its string name - "two_butons"
```

How can I get a class instance, knowing only its name?

Or - can I get userControl instance in some other way?

Many thanks.

Comment: When you say "name", do you mean the *local* name, the *full* name (including namespace), or the *qualified* name (including assembly and namespace)?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `assembly.GetType(someString)`, where `assembly` is the `Assembly` instance that contains the type.  (eg, `typeof(YourOtherType).Assembly`)

Comment: Ok. I'll try it. Wanna ask more - won't this method will take all memory? I create userControl instance for every listBoxItem - is it OK?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: two_butons b2 = new two_butons(); ??